# How to set global datetime nodejs app

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, date, momentjs

For testing purpose I want to simulate a global datetime in Nodejs. But can't find a good solution without refactoring my code. Is there maybe an environment variable I can set?
We're using the Moment.js library.

Comment: An example of how you intend on using it would help.

Comment: @James i just wan't to know if it's possible to change the date in the app globaly, like setting the node environment.
Our app compares records in the database if they are active on a certain date. To test this we have a mock db with data, that contains dates. So i want to simulate the date to check which items are active and which are nor.

Comment: Can't you just mock `Date()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
global.dateTime = Date.now()
```

Hope it helps.